# How can I stream MJPG/JPG video from Raspberry Pi to other computer?

Tags: python, encoding, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I am currently trying to stream video from my Raspberry Pi 4 (Bullseye) with camera module 3 to a separate machine.

I understand I can use things like VLC, but I am also wanting to be able to use stream data for other things as well. I have set up my Pi and have a established a connection between my machine and my Pi, there also is a flow of data between the two which I believe is my encoded JPEG data. However, I either have my logic wrong, or am encoding/decoding wrong and I would appreciate another pair of eyes.

Here is my producer/encoder ran on the Pi:

```
import socket
import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import JpegEncoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput

picam2 = Picamera2()
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration({"size": (1280, 720)})
picam2.configure(video_config)

encoder = JpegEncoder()

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(("my-pi-ip" , 10001))
    sock.listen()

    picam2.encoders = encoder

    print("\nAwaiting connection...")
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    stream = conn.makefile("wb")
    encoder.output = FileOutput(stream)
    
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data.decode() == "ping":
        print("ping recieved from: " + str(conn))

    picam2.start_encoder()
    picam2.start()
    print("camera started")
    
    time.sleep(15)
    
    picam2.stop()
    print("\ncamera stopped")
    picam2.stop_encoder()
    conn.close()
```

Here is the consumer/decoder ran on my machine:

```
import cv2
import socket
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

# Create a socket client
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("my-pi-ip", 10001))

ping_exception_flag = False

# Function to periodically send ping to the server
def send_ping():
    print("Ping thread started")
    while True:
        try:
            print("Sending ping")
            client_socket.send(b'ping')
            print("Ping sent")
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            print("Server disconnected")
            ping_exception_flag = True


# Start the ping thread
ping_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_ping)
ping_thread.start()

# Receive and display the video stream
while not ping_exception_flag:
    data = b''
    while b'--FRAME' not in data:
        data += client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        #debug purposes

    frames = data.split(b'--FRAME')
    print(data)

    for frame in frames:
        print(frame)
        if b'Content-Type: image/jpeg' in frame:
            image_data = frame.split(b'\r\n\r\n')[1]
            image_array = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8)
            frame = cv2.imdecode(image_array, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            if frame is not None:
                cv2.imshow("Video Stream", frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

# Cleanup
ping_thread.join()  # Wait for the ping thread to finish
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
client_socket.close()
```

And finally here is a sample output that I am getting from 'data' when printing the result for debugging:

b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\r\t\n ...

I know there are QoL things that need to be changed with the code as a whole, but as of right now I am just concerned with the streaming aspect. The end goal is to implement Azure AI Vision or some other sort of computer vision with real time analysis, so If there are other ways to go about this, I am all ears and would appreciate the input!

Edit: I think my issue is that I am searching for packet headers when I'm trying a to do a direct socket connection, and I'm not adding headers to them, so they simply don't exist.

Comment: If you can view it with VLC, you can also stream it with VLC, in several codecs and streaming protocols.

Comment: @KlausD. it's strange, I have a separate program that uses HTTP to make a super simple webpage that streams and VLC has no issue getting the stream from that, but from this here it is struggling.